# How to setup storybook in a separate app within a mono repo? Next JS 13

Tags: next.js, importerror, storybook, monorepo, next.js13

I'm trying to separate out my storybook from my main web app so that I can deploy my storybook separately from my web app. But I'm running into some trouble with imports. My components live under the web app. The storybook is running fine when running under the web app but not when I moved it out.

File Structure:

```
/app
|--/myWebApp
|-----package.json
|-----(next js files and components)
|--/storybook
|-----/.storybook
|-------/stories
|-------main.js
|-------preview.js
|-----next.config.js
|-----package.json
```

app/storybook/next.config.js

```
    const withTM = require('next-transpile-module')(['@monorepo/myWebApp'])
    module.export = withTM()
```

app/myWebApp/package.json

```
{
    "name": "@monorepo/myWebApp",
    "main": "@monorepo/myWebApp"
}
```

Then in my stories where i'm importing a component from `app/myWebApp` i'm using imports like `@monorepo/myWebApp/src/components/button`.

But when this button/component is referencing other components using Next's absolute imports like `src/components/text` the story book throws the build error saying it can't be resolved. The storybook page comes up but fails to render the components due to the reference errors of the absolute import.

How could I resolve this issue? Am I missing a configuration? Or maybe unrelated do I need to have a page file in order to serve this storybook at a specific route?

Adding the next-transpile-module was what I tried and found online for accessing components from another app. But it mentioned the `main` should be pointing to the same file in both apps but my storybook wouldn't have a matching with app...

I'm pretty new to Next JS, would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.